# RDS Performance Insights doesn't display all top SQL stats

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have an issue with Performance Insights for one of our RDS instances.
We have two mysql 5.7.38, db.m5.xlarge instances. Both DB uses the same parameter group, security groups and the monitoring role. One instance is a primary, and the second is a read-only replica. We enabled Performance Insights and Enhanced monitoring on both of them.

Unfortunately, only the read-only replica shows full stats for top SQL queries.

Primary DB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghoYr.png)

Read-only replica
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNMUO.png)

I have trierd disable and enable Performance Insights and reboot instance, no luck so far.

We would like to get a full stats for the top SQL queries inside Performance Insights.